# Ionic3 Events not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) in my Ionic3 app.

For e.g I am using events to redirect the user to login screen whenever any API response gives HTTP 401.

So in my **`app.component.ts`** file I am doing:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Toast } from '../utilities/toast';
import { LocalStorage } from '../utilities/localstorage';
import { Platform, MenuController, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any;
  pages: Array<{title: string, pageName: string}>;
  guardian: any;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public events: Events,
    public network: Network,
    public toast: Toast,
    public storage: LocalStorage)
  {
    console.log('before unauthorised'); //This line works when a 401 occurs
    events.subscribe('unauthorised', () => {
      console.log('user unauthorised take to login page'); //While this doesn't
      this.storage.clear();
      this.nav.setRoot('LoginPage');
    });
  }
}
```

And in my api services file I am publishing the event:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Toast } from '../utilities/toast';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalStorage } from '../utilities/localstorage';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceProvider {
    constructor(public http: Http,
        private toast: Toast,
        public events: Events,
        private storage: LocalStorage) {

    }

    getErrorMessages(errors) {
        if (errors.status == 401) {  //<= unauthorised
            this.toast.present('You need to login first!');
            this.events.publish('unauthorised');
        }

        let error_messages = [];
        if (errors.status == 422) { //<= validation error
            let validation_messages = JSON.parse(errors.text())
            for (var key in validation_messages) {
                if (validation_messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var messages = validation_messages[key];
                    error_messages.push(...messages);
                }
            }
        } else { //<= timeout or http code 500, 405 etc.
            error_messages.push('Technical error occured... please try again later.');
        }
        return error_messages;
    }

}
```

What could have been the problem? The code looks correct as per the ionic documentation.

**EDIT** I am adding the child service code. So basically the service provider is the parent class for all the api services. For e.g the auth service class extends the service class above and has the following method for fetching auth user:

```
getAuthUser() {
    console.log('will fetch auth');

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getAuthToken()
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(this.getApiUrl() + '/me', options)
            .timeout(this.getTimeOut())
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(response => {
                resolve(response);
                this.events.publish('auth_user_fetched');
            }, errors => {
                reject(this.getErrorMessages(errors));
            });
    });
}
```

Not that I am not using try catch here.

Comment: The code is correct, did you tried to _console.log_ errors ? Can you edit your question with requets catch ?

Comment: @Jamie I did console log and the log under subscribe doesn't prints anything. Moreover I am not getting any console errors.

Comment: Though I am getting the log when the event is getting published: 
`this.toast.present('You need to login first!');
            this.events.publish('unauthorised');`

Comment: I think you are losing context, try my answer

Comment: It not, can you show me your http request or any log error ?

Comment: Jamie, edited the question. Btw, I am not gettings any error :/

Comment: Inside _getErrorMessages_ check _this.events._channels_ here you can see all events subscribed, check if 'unauthorised' is there.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that `app.component.ts` acts as a Parent and your provider as a child. Therefore, the event cannot be published and subscribed.

In your code `console.log('before unauthorised'); //This line works when a 401 occurs` works because `app.component.ts` is a file that gets called everytime you do some activity. And this console is written in the constructor(resulting in it called everytime).

What you can do is instead of using event for unauthorized functionality. Create a function in your provider itself that will do

```
unauthorized() {
      console.log('user unauthorised take to login page'); 
      this.storage.clear();
      this.nav.setRoot('LoginPage');
}
```